# Oracle APEX 21.2 - What is the use of "Execution Scope" setting under process in the context of Interactive Grids

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to understand the use of the "Execution Scope" setting found under processes of IG Automatic Row Processing as well as validations with IG mapped as editable region.

[image]

I kept logging in these process and tried deleting and updating records, but both the settings seems to work the same

Also

[image]

With the above code, I deleted a record and it got deleted without raising the validation.

The same when I have the execution scope as "For created and Modified Rows".

Can someone help me understand this setting?

PS: When I set the "Always Execute" this process also gets executed on Delete although the help text for this setting is conveying entirely different explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While in Apex, navigate to *any* property and check help related to it, e.g.

[image]

It describes what it is used for, so  - I suggest you read it.

Also, almost everything is covered in documentation, e.g. [Understanding page processes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/bldr_pg_procs.htm#HTMDB04019).

Comment: Yes @Littlefoot I am aware. But the problem is it doesn't work according to the documentation. As mentioned in the question, it works the same for both the options under Execution Scope